# Why am I having double child window in applications?

Tags: pantheon, gala

[image: Double child window in applications]
It's happening in various applications, not only with mysql workbench, I tried to open a bug report, but I don't know where the elementary os bug report is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Which elementaryOS version are you using? Seems like an issue with Pantheon, therefore you might try to reinstall pantheon-desktop without having to wipe your hdd/ssd.

Comment: I'm using loki version and it's a clean installation

Comment: Is it also occuring when you use preinstalled applications? Maybe you might give another example so I can try to replicate the error?

Comment: It's happening with PlayOnLinux too

Comment: Same problem with transcribe! (a commercial closed source software with a binary built on ubuntu 14.04 according to https://www.seventhstring.com/xscribe/linux_distros_86.html )

Answer (score 0):

> There's a shell script (/etc/profile.d/gtk-csd.sh) that exports GTK_CSD=1. I would highly recommend not deleting this shell script as it makes all of the dialog boxes look a bit weird and breaks the open file/folder dialog in some cases.

see this issues: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/244#issuecomment-438259702